# Expose object from class library using WCF

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I'm using a class library that exposes a few objects.  These objects have a couple of properties that hold data my clients need.  I'd like to create a WCF service that returns the objects to my clients but I cannot update the class library in order to add the DataContract and DataMember attributes.  What is the easiest way of exposing these objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [DataContractSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540.aspx).

> ...You can apply the DataContract
>   attribute to the Person class, but
>   this is not always possible. For
>   example, the Person class can be
>   defined in a separate assembly over
>   which you have no control.
>
> Given this restriction, one way to
>   serialize the Person class is to
>   substitute it with another class that
>   is marked with DataContractAttribute
>   and copy over necessary data to the
>   new class. The objective is to make
>   the Person class appear as a
>   DataContract to the
>   DataContractSerializer. Note that this
>   is one way to serialize non-data
>   contract classes. ...

Comment: Thanks - MSDN suggests using Data Contract Surrogates but I wasn't sure if there was an easier answer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes on your object, you'll have to find a way to expose them using the XmlSerializer.

You can define a service or an operation to use the XmlSerializer by specifying the [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute on either your Service contract, or an individual OperationContract.

Does that help maybe?

Marc

Comment: I think Brian's answer is more close to the point.  I have no control over the class library objects - his answer is closer to what MSDN suggests.